# My say command keeps running into errors and i cant figure out how to do it help would be appricated

Tags: python, discord.py

so im trying to do a say command that makes it so if a member of my servers discord development team uses it then it will send a message to the announcement channel. it wont send message or delete the message at all  im using the rewrite of discord.py and python this is my code

`@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('Manager')
async def say(ctx, content):
    channel = ctx.guild.get_channel("714229744798925012")
    await channel.send(channel,content)
    await Message_delete(content)`
idk why this is happenening also it says manager cos im testing it out on a test server before it goes live

Answer (score -2):

You can't pass a text to send as an parameter to a @bot.command function. Generally U use this:

```
async def say(ctx, *args):
```

args is a tuple of the space separated substrings of you message (aka words ;-)). For example

```
!say Hello world
```

will present you with

```
args = ("Hello", "world")
```

to convert the tuple int a string simply use:

```
message = ""
message = ' '.join(args)
```

in total:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('Manager')
async def say(ctx, *args):
    message = ""
    message = ' '.join(args)
    channel = ctx.guild.get_channel("714229744798925012")
    await channel.send(channel, message)
```

If you wish to add a command to delete the message later, I suggest to store it's ID for later usage.

Comment: "You can't pass a text to send as an parameter to a @bot.command function" This is incorrect. You should refer to this part of the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments

Comment: What I meant to say is, that you can't pass it as a string. The link you provided leads to exactly the solution I described above.

Comment: You can use `async def say(ctx, *, content):`, which means the full string after the command is invoked will be stored in `content`